# How to save the screenshot in particular folder using python

Tags: python, selenium

I have written the below script for taking a screenshot. Currently, it saves the file in the same directory as the python file is located. I want to save the screenshot in a particular folder.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import option
import time

#PhantomJS
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'D:\PhantomJS\phantomjs-2.1.1-
windows\bin\phantomjs.exe')

#Selenium
#driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\Selenium\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")

#Maximizes window to full screen
driver.maximize_window()

#Gets the URL for OMS
driver.get(option.OMS_QUERY)

#Gets the username & Password
driver.find_element_by_xpath(option.LOG_IN).click()
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(option.USERNAME)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(option.ENTER).click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(option.PASSWORD)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(option.ENTER).click()
time.sleep(15)

#Saves the screenshot for OMS_SWR
driver.save_screenshot('oms_swr.png')

#Gets the URL for DMS
driver.get(option.DMS_QUERY)
time.sleep(15)

#Saves the screenshot for DMS_SWR
driver.save_screenshot('dms_swr.png')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: `driver.save_screenshot('/path/to/oms_swr.png')` does not work?

Comment: No, it does not work

Comment: If the path does not exist, you should create it first.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set path where you want to store it, Store in system drive like this

```
driver.save_screenshot('D:/Folder_name/dms_swr.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the **`screenshot`** in a particular folder you can use either of the following options :

- Within your Project space :

  ```
  driver.save_screenshot('./project_directory/save_screenshot.png')
  ```
- Within your System :

  ```
  driver.save_screenshot('C:/system_directory/save_screenshot.png')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

i tried doing this as well. it didnt work. i created a directory named image an then tried using driver.save_screenshot('/Users/name/PycharmProjects/RunPage/image/homepage.png')

but this didnt work

I also tried

driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/Users/name/PycharmProjects/RunPage/image/homepage.png')

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30142044)